# Javascript, XML to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

this is my first post, sorry if i have made any mistakes, i am trying to populate xml data from a local xml file into a html table, below is the html content:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>(xmldata)</td>
      <td>(xmldata)</td>
      <td>(xmldata)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>(xmldata)</td>
      <td>(xmldata)</td>
      <td>(xmldata)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>(xmldata)</td>
      <td>(xmldata)</td>
      <td>(xmldata)</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the javascript:

```
< script >

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/xmltest.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.write("<table><tr><th>Type</th><th>Gender</th><th>Age</th></tr>");
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("test");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Type")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Gender")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Age")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");

< /script>
```

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<test Type="S" Gender="Male" Age="11"/>
<test Type="S" Gender="Female" Age="54"/>
<test Type="M" Gender="Female" Age="37"/>
<test Type="M" Gender="Female" Age="35" />
<test Type="M" Gender="Male" Age="22"/>
<test Type="A" Gender="Female" Age="29"/>
<test Type="Unknown"/>
<test Type="I" Gender="Female" Age="72"/>
```

any comment/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Is it a **valid** XML file?

Comment: Can't use `document.write` after the page has loaded, it will wipe out the whole page. Other than that you haven't provided a question or problem statement

Comment: Yes, its a valid xml file. sorry i am very new to this..how would i accomplish this task of adding data from an xml file into a already made table in html if not document.write?

Comment: Surely a valid XML file must start with this statement `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` Yours does not. So its not valid.

Comment: Removed snippet wrappers as it is not runnable in this state

Comment: i have updated, sorry

Comment: You'll also need a root element on your XML document.

Comment: @Gawai, to add data to an existing table you can use insertRow(), manual: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without jquery.

Is only used to append the html to the div (limitation fiddle)
Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/oqd9g85s/2/

Code:

```
var xml = '<root><test Type="S" Gender="Male" Age="11"/>' +
'<test Type="S" Gender="Female" Age="54"/>' +
'<test Type="M" Gender="Female" Age="37"/>' +
'<test Type="M" Gender="Female" Age="35" />' +
'<test Type="M" Gender="Male" Age="22"/>' +
'<test Type="A" Gender="Female" Age="29"/>' +
'<test Type="Unknown"/>' +
'<test Type="I" Gender="Female" Age="72"/></root>';

// create xml object
if (window.DOMParser) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        return ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
    };
} else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" && new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
        return xmlDoc;
    };
} else {
    parseXml = function() { return null; }
}

var xmlDoc = parseXml(xml);


 var htm = "<table><tr><th>Type</th><th>Gender</th><th>Age</th></tr>";
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("test");


for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    try{  htm+= "<tr><td>";

  htm+= x[i].attributes["Type"].value;
  htm+= "</td><td>";

 htm+=x[i].attributes["Gender"].value;
  htm+= "</td><td>";

  htm+= x[i].attributes["Age"].value;
  htm+= "</td></tr>";
       }
    catch (exception) {console.log('unknown stuff in position: ' + i);}
}
htm+= "</table>";
alert(htm);
$('#wrapper').html(htm);
```

**Update here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/g429vy4p/
You will find how it works in comments.

HTML:

#### Contents of the file:

```
<h3>Html Output:</h3>
<div id='wrapper'></div>
```

and pure javascript **NO JQUERY**
    //read your file using FileReader
    function readSingleFile(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
          if (!file) {
            return;
          }
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
        var contents = e.target.result;
        displayFileContents(contents);
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }

```
//here you have parse and inser the html
function displayFileContents(contents) {
    var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
    element.innerHTML = htmlEscape(contents);
    generateHTMLOutput('wrapper', contents)   
}
//escape html chars to show original xml file
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}

//attach event on file upload
document.getElementById('file-input')
  .addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);



// create xml object function declaration variations
if (window.DOMParser) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        return ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
    };
} else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" && new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
        return xmlDoc;
    };
} else {
    parseXml = function() { return null; }
}

//insert your output in page
//@ wrraperID : <div id='wrapper'></div>
//@ contentasstring : string to be parsed as XML doc, need to be corect formated, no validation here
function generateHTMLOutput(wrapperId, contentasstring)
{
    var xmlDoc = parseXml(contentasstring);        
    var htm = "<table><tr><th>Type</th><th>Gender</th><th>Age</th></tr>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("test");    

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    try{  htm+= "<tr><td>";

      htm+= x[i].attributes["Type"].value;
      htm+= "</td><td>";

      htm+=x[i].attributes["Gender"].value;
      htm+= "</td><td>";

      htm+= x[i].attributes["Age"].value;
      htm+= "</td></tr>";
           }
        catch (exception) {console.log('unknown stuff in position: ' + i);}
    }
    var elem = document.getElementById(wrapperId);
    elem.innerHTML = htm;  
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your method and answer, which works!! how would i get the data from the xml file if it was on my local computer?

Comment: I'll help you tomorrow or on Monday, share more details, like you wan't to open from ///filepath or via ajax call :)

Comment: Update: Now file select from computer, removed jQuerry, pure javascript, hope you'll understand, please mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Example for iterating through xml with jquery:

example xml file:

```
<document>
 <row>
  <Col0>1</Col0 >
  <Col1>2</Col1 >
  <Col2>3</Col2 >
 </row>
 <row>
  <Col0>2</Col0 >
  <Col1>4</Col1 >
  <Col2>5</Col2 >
 </row>
</document>
```

resulting jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "example.xml", 
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {  
   $(xml).find('row').each(function(){  
    var Col0 = $(this).find('Col0').text();
    var Col1 = $(this).find('Col1').text();
    var Col2 = $(this).find('Col2').text();
// do your output here by modifying an element in dom or adding one
   });
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: OP did not specify using jQuery in their question, and in fact went out of the way to use native JS.

Comment: I'm not sure what is question is then, to be honest

Comment: sorry, i don't know the best method to use however all i am trying to archive is, when i load my html file in a browser it has the data from the xml populated within the rows Type Gender Age.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you have with your script?

Comment: yes, i think i misunderstood the logic i am very new to this....i am trying to get information from an xml file as shown in the first post which is located locally on my computer and display the data in an already existing emtpy table in html which is also in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using document.write, use DOM methods to add the new elements to the page. Assuming you've obtained valid XML into the variable `xmlDoc`, you could do something like:

```js
(function() {
  var oParser, xmlString, xmlDoc, tbody, fields;

  // Ignore this; I'm populating an example XML doc
  oParser = new DOMParser();
  xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><test Type="S" Gender="Male" Age="11"/> <test Type="S" Gender="Female" Age="54"/> <test Type="M" Gender="Female" Age="37"/> <test Type="M" Gender="Female" Age="35" /> <test Type="M" Gender="Male" Age="22"/> <test Type="A" Gender="Female" Age="29"/> <test Type="Unknown"/> <test Type="I" Gender="Female" Age="72"/></root>';
  xmlDoc = oParser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

  // Assuming you've got a valid xmlDoc with the structure you described

  // The order in which the fields of your nodes should be displayed.
  fields = ['Type', 'Gender', 'Age'];

  tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
  appendToTbody = makeAppender(tbody);

  function addNodeToTable(n) {
    var o = objectFromNode(n);
    var r = rowFromObject(o);
    appendToTbody(r);
  }

  function buildTable(sourceXmlDoc) {
    // the first element of the source doc will be the root element
    var children = toArray(sourceXmlDoc.firstElementChild.children);
    children.forEach(addNodeToTable);
  };

  function getPropertyFromObject(o) {
    return function(prop) {
      return o[prop];
    };
  }

  function makeAppender(e) {
    return function(child) {
      e.appendChild(child);
    }
  }

  function objectFromNode(n) {
    var o = {};
    var setter = setPropertyForObjectFromNode(o, n);
    fields.forEach(setter);
    return o;
  };

  function setPropertyForObjectFromNode(o, n) {
    return function(prop) {
      var attr = n.attributes.getNamedItem(prop);
      o[prop] = attr ? attr.value : undefined;
    };
  }

  function rowFromObject(o) {
    var tr, tds, values;
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    appendToTr = makeAppender(tr);
    values = valuesFromObject(o);
    tds = values.map(tdWithText);
    tds.forEach(appendToTr);
    return tr;
  };

  function tdWithText(text) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var tn = document.createTextNode(text);
    td.appendChild(tn);
    return td;
  };

  function toArray(o) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(o);
  }

  function valuesFromObject(o) {
    var getter = getPropertyFromObject(o);
    return fields.map(getter);
  }

  buildTable(xmlDoc);
}());
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```